# Como abrir um link href via console dev tolls?

Tags: javascript, node.js, dev-tools

Como posso, utilizando o console do Chrome (dev tools), abrir o link do exemplo abaixo na mesma janela que está aberta o site:

*Exemplo:*
site: https://musica.cancaonova.com/

**local do link**: document.querySelector('#menu-item-5972 a').href

link: https://musica.cancaonova.com/

O comando abaixo abre em nova aba, mas eu preciso que seja aberto na mesma aba.

```
open(document.querySelector('#menu-item-5972 a').href)
```

Answer (score 1):

Ao invés de usar `window.open` tenta utilizar o `window.location.href`

Por exemplo:  `window.location.href = "url";`

Comment: Consegui pelo comando:
`location.replace(document.querySelector('#menu-item-5972 a').href)`

Comment: @Nay-ton Boa ideia, este comando também funciona!